# Output of program have more lines than it should

Tags: python

I've been trying to write a program that reads lines and for every line it should return single letter. Unfortunately the problem is in the output there are more lines (about 20 for 160k lines of input) than in the input.

I would be more than happy if someone could tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import Counter
from re import split
import re
from itertools import islice
import random

def checkisin(femalewords, malewords, testin):
    with open(femalewords) as filein:
        femalewordslist = filein.readlines()
    with open(malewords) as filein:
        malewordslist = filein.readlines()

    letters = "FM"

    with open(testin, "rU") as filein:
        for line in filein:
            malecounter = 0
            femalecounter = 0
            linia = line.rstrip()
            if any(word in linia for word in femalewordslist):
                femalecounter = femalecounter+1
            if any(word in linia for word in malewordslist):
                malecounter = malecounter+1
            if malecounter > femalecounter:
                print "M"
            elif malecounter < femalecounter:
                print "F"
            elif malecounter == femalecounter:
                print random.choice(letters)

checkisin("femaletopwords.txt", "maletopwords.txt", "in2.tsv")
```

Comment: This looks like it outputs one single-character line for each line in "in2.tsv". What happens when you run it? Did you try printing the line in addition to the letter, just for debugging, to see what went wrong? Or perhaps setting a break point for debugger?

Comment: I'm not quite sure your usage of `any(word in linia for word in list)` is correct because I think that it will always return `True`. That is because `if word` always executes when `word != False`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually, if `word` and `linia` are strings, then `word in linia` is true if `word` is substring of `linia`, so that line should do what it looks like it does.

Comment: How do you know the number of lines are different? That is, what mechanism do you use to count the lines outside of this program?

Comment: @tdelaney I just compared input and output file with wc -l
>zvone Yeah, i want lines with single letter in every one of them in output. When i run it it returns me result that look like i want, but there are simply too many lines.

Comment: You are using python's universal newlines mode `"rU"` which may generate a different number of lines than other programs, especially if there is an unattached `"\r"` in the file. When the `for` loop is done, do a `print repr(filein.newlines)`. If its got `\r` , there's your problem.

Comment: Open with just `"r` "and see how that goes.

Comment: Yeah, that "rU" was the problem. Thank you very much for help. Is there any way to upvote you guys?

Comment: Don't worry about the upvote. It was just a guess and not quite "answer worthy" until you had a chance to test it.

Answer (score 0):

As user tdelaney said:
"You are using python's universal newlines mode "rU" which may generate a different number of lines than other programs, especially if there is an unattached "\r" in the file. When the for loop is done, do a print repr(filein.newlines). If its got \r , there's your problem."

It fixed the problem.